# Dynamically change Min and Max date

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, ag-grid

I'm using [jquery multiple date picker](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/) in Angular 4 Ag-Grid.

I've scenario where the min and max date will change dynamically.

Issue is the updated min and max value is updated only after i refresh the page.

Is there any way to update the calendar without page refresh.

I've created a sample plunker to have an idea
https://plnkr.co/edit/Gl3dSR8qzeQaiXKmhCZH?p=preview

```
function getDatePicker() {
  function Datepicker() {}
  Datepicker.prototype.init = function(params) {
    this.eInput = document.createElement("span");
    this.eInput.value = params.value;
    $(this.eInput).multiDatesPicker({ 
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      minDate: '01/01/2018',
      maxDate: '31/05/2018',
      addDates:['01/01/2018','01/02/2018','01/03/2018']

    });
  };
  Datepicker.prototype.getGui = function() {
    return this.eInput;

  };
  Datepicker.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function() {
    this.eInput.focus();
    this.eInput.select();
  };
  Datepicker.prototype.getValue = function() {
    return this.eInput.value;
  };
  Datepicker.prototype.destroy = function() {};
  Datepicker.prototype.isPopup = function() {
    return true;
  };
  return Datepicker;
}
```